# Show/Hide with Multiple Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am very new to building forms with js. I copied and applied a bit of code to get fields to pop up depending on the Radio button I select. This works great for two radio buttons, but my issues is that I want to include several (5+) and would like to reset the fields with every change.

I was thinking I can input additional code to reset all fields "onchange" but I can't get this piece of code to work... here is what I copied and modified for my use:

works great with 2 buttons as designed:

```
{
  toggleSelectionFields: function() {
      var isLaptop = ca_fdIsSelectRadio('showhide','group','short');
      if (isLaptop) {
        ca_fdHideField('showhide','longfields');
        ca_fdShowField('showhide','shortfields');
      } else {
        ca_fdHideField('showhide','shortfields');
        ca_fdShowField('showhide','longfields');
      }
    }
}
```

Here is what I tried to do:

```
{
    toggleSelectionFields: function() {
        Var discovery = ca_fdIsSelectRadio('phone','deskphone4610','selectproblem','SelectIssue','discovery');
        Var headset = ca_fdIsSelectRadio('phone','deskphone4610','selectproblem','SelectIssue','headset');
        Var fac = ca_fdIsSelectRadio('phone','deskphone4610','selectproblem','SelectIssue','feature');
        Var calls = ca_fdIsSelectRadio('phone','deskphone4610','selectproblem','SelectIssue','calls');
        if (discovery) 
        {ca_fdShowField('phone','deskphone4610','selectproblem','discovermode')}
        if (headset)
        {ca_fdShowField('phone','deskphone4610','selectproblem','headset')} 
        if (fac)
        {ca_fdShowField('phone','deskphone4610','selectproblem','feature')}
        if (calls)
        {ca_fdShowField('phone','deskphone4610','selectproblem','calls')}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: out of curiosity... why is this tagged as java ?

Comment: I assume you meant Javascript instead of Java when tagging this, so I've corrected that - but this should not be tagged with PHP as it has nothing to do with PHP. Just because you may use PHP does not necessarily mean that PHP is part of the problem or solution. In this case, your issue is with Javascript and to an extent, HTML, so those are valid tags.

Comment: Can you share a JSfiddle with HTML/JS and explain in more detail what you're seeing vs. what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a JavaScript question (not Java) and related to a particular framework (CA Service Catalog), so questions about how to do things with particular CA functions would probably be best answered on the [CA Service Management Global User Community](https://communities.ca.com/web/ca-service-management-global-user-community/message-board/) message boards.

As a general logic/JavaScript question, though, you need to hide the fields you don't want to see in addition to showing the ones you do want to see.  Notice that your first example calls `ca_fdHideField` to hide one set of fields, then `ca_fdShowField` to show the other.  If you don't want to duplicate a lot of code, you could hide them all before the `if` statements, then just show the one that corresponds with the radio button that was selected:

```
ca_fdHideField(...)
ca_fdHideField(...)
...
if (discovery) {
...
}
```

etc.

Comment: You guys are right, I mislabeled the tags, I shouldn't have been lazy with them.... First post on this site, looks like I gotta stay in line for you nerds :p. I was lazy with the tags and should have been.

Comment: Zebby Dee, thank you that general question is what I was shooting for.... I was trying to avoid having to write a ton of code as I have a dozen Radio Buttons with as twice as many subsequent fields.

Comment: Welcome to SO (I'm pretty new here myself). I hope you don't feel like people are too nitpicky - it's just that you'll get better (and faster) answers to your questions if you tag them correctly. I happen to be familiar with both Java and JavaScript, but outside of some syntax similarities they're very different languages.

Comment: I'm also currently whoring for "Accept"s,  if you're so inclined ;)

Comment: If you're going to be writing code like this a lot, it's worth looking into using a loop to run through the fields. A simple way is to use some kind of naming convention, like "phone1", "phone2" etc. for the groups, then `for (var i=1; i<=[highest number]; i++) { ca_fdHideField('phone' + i, [etc.]); }` to hide them.  Another way would be to use the HTML DOM to get all elements with a certain ID or tag and use a for..in loop, but that's a little more advanced.

Comment: Well, figured it out... simple stupid... when I put in the "onclick" command for the field it never saved. I was too busy looking into the code and how CA's APIs interacted to notice at first.... THANKS!